# How to provide a progress bar for pandas resample

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I have recently found the excellent [tqdm package](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) which makes displaying progress bars about everything very easy. It has some integration with pandas as well which provides a progress bar for when using [.progress_apply() instead of .apply()](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#pandas-integration).

In my current project I am using pandas resampling some data which takes quite a while. Is there some way to get a progress bar for the resampling process?

Here is the line I want progress for:

```py
df_plot_data = changelog_dataframe.groupby(["key","field"]).resample("W").last().fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: are you also using a jupyter notebook?

Comment: no I am not using a jupyter notebook for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
changelog_dataframe.groupby(["key","field"]).progress_apply(lambda x : x.resample("W").last()).fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: This gives me a progressbar. Still need to confirm if it produces the same data. Dataframe.info() looks slightly different.

Comment: I updated it.  Moved fillna outside of the aggregation.  See if that works.

Comment: How did you find the performance of this solution vs. a straight call to resample? I assume that it's a bit slower, but I'd love to use it if not.